# small icon on push notification not showing on android?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, clevertap

I have added small icon in push notification but still not showing. I am using android 10 emulator. My icon have fulfill requirement that using white color with no background and store in mipmap folder. I have tried some solution on previous same question on stackoverflow but still not working.
this is my code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Push notification icon still showing like this
[image]

I have tried add this code on android manifest but still not working too

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
```

my targetSDK is 29

Did you ever encounter same issues and solved ?

Comment: Did you try using other images from `drawable` folder?

Comment: @SamChen i have tried but not working too

Comment: @FairuzYassar  I would also reccomend you to try loading an image from the `drawable` folder. What I always do is, get an .svg icon first, import it in the `drawable` folder as a vector asset, the result of this step would be a generated .xml layout file. 
Finally call this layout file `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_yourIcon)` in the `NotificationCompat.Builder` like this and it will work.

Comment: @BWappsandmore I have tried your solution but notification icon still showing grey square like above picture

Comment: @Fairuz Yassar search the Internet for a free `.svg` icon. Download it. In Android Studio right click on your `drawable` folder and then choose `New -> Vector Asset`. Choose Local file (SVG, PSD) as Asset Type. Select the icon that you downloaded. As soon the `.xml` layout file has been generated from it, click on it to edit. Edit `android:height="24dp"` and `android:width="24dp"` or play around with the size, 36dp, or 48dp. You will see the preview from the icon on the left side of the editor. Attach this file to your Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Action Bar Icons require a file size of **24×24 pixels** at the baseline size (MDPI). However, the image itself must be no more than **22×22 pixels centered** within the Icon file.

**The Icon Design must be single color white, #ffffff.**

```
MDPI - 24 x 24  (drawable-mdpi)
HDPI - 36 x 36  (drawable-hdpi)
XHDPI - 48 x 48  (drawable-xhdpi)
XXHDPI - 72 x 72  (drawable-xxhdpi)
XXXHDPI - 96 x 96  (drawable-xxxhdpi)
```

For more details look [Android Cheatsheet](http://petrnohejl.github.io/android-cheatsheet-for-graphic-designers/) and [Official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I have all of this size and icon design has follow the rule but icon still not showing. i created icon using this tools https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit

Comment: Use Drawable Folder
For data Message  => .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
For Notification Message => android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification"